# Cannot import QISKIT "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit._accelerate'"

Tags: python, anaconda, qiskit

I'm trying to use qiskit in virtual environment via Anaconda, however although I see qiskit as installed, importing qiskit always fails with:

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qiskit._accelerate'

I can't find information about this anywhere. What is this module? What is wrong with the environment? It seems there's nothing called qiskit._accelerate

Comment: What steps did you go through to set up your virtual environment and install Qiskit? Same issue was reported in Spyder on https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/27097/qiskit-from-anaconda-spyder-missing-module-error

Comment: @JosephGeipel I've installed Python and then qiskit using pip. I have Python 3.9.12 and qiskit 0.37.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the issue thanks to Joseph Geipel's advice.
There's some compatibility issue between Python and Qiskit.

Python 3.9.12 and Qiskit 0.37.0 seem not to work well together.
When I've created a new environment with Python 3.8.13 and the same version of Qiskit, the problem was solved.